# How to set columns while saving in csv using scrapy

Tags: html, css, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

so basically i am scraping data off the web and i have an items file which is imported to my main spider file. Now when i scrape data and store it in containers and save it as csv, the links columns always ends up being the first column in the csv. How do set custom placement of columns?

```
       pName = response.css('#search .a-size-medium').css('::text').extract()
        pPrice = response.css('#search .a-price-whole').css('::text').extract()
        imgs = response.css('.sbv-product-img , .s-image-fixed-height .s-image').css('::attr(src)').extract()

        for prod in zip(pName , pPrice , imgs):        
            items['prodName'] = prod[0]     
            items['price'] = prod[1]        
            items['imgLink'] = prod[2]      
            
            yield items
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS` setting either in your `settings.py` file or in your spiders `custom_settings` attribute.  The columns will be in the order you set them to in the value of the setting.

For example:

```py
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    custom_settings = {
        "FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS": ["prodName", "price", "imgLink"]
    }
```

or in `settings.py`:

```py
FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS=["prodName", "price", "imgLink"]
```

scrapy docs [link](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-fields) and [link2](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#csv)

Comment: could you give me some tips on where to learn advanced scrapy and webscraping from so i can work for people?

Comment: @FaizanUlHaq  Honestly the best advice is to simply read the documentation, and get really familiar with the source code.